# Converting accented characters in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, text, encoding, character-encoding, multibyte

Is there an existing function to replace accented characters with unadorned characters in PostgreSQL?  Characters like `å` and `ø` should become `a` and `o` respectively.

The closest thing I could find is the translate function, given the example in the comments section found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/multibyte.html).

> Some commonly used accented characters
>   can be searched using the following
>   function:
>
> translate(search_terms,
>   '\303\200\303\201\303\202\303\203\303\204\303\205\303\206\303\207\303\210\303\211\303\212\303\213\303\214\303\215\303\216\303\217\303\221\303\222\303\223\303\224\303\225\303\226\303\230\303\231\303\232\303\233\303\234\303\235\303\237\303\240\303\241\303\242\303\243\303\244\303\245\303\246\303\247\303\250\303\251\303\252\303\253\303\254\303\255\303\256\303\257\303\261\303\262\303\263\303\264\303\265\303\266\303\270\303\271\303\272\303\273\303\274\303\275\303\277','AAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYSaaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this just for indexing/sorting? If so, you could use [this postgresql extension](http://www.public-software-group.org/pg_collkey), which provides proper Unicode collation. The same group has [a postgresql extension for doing normalization](http://www.public-software-group.org/utf8proc).

Comment: Yes, this is for indexing, as I'll be searching based upon raw user input. The normalization extension looks like it's what I'm looking for, but I'll have to look further into the first link you provided too, as maybe I should use that instead.